# While running the Ruby on Rails Project getting error as per the below format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backend

Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.                                                                                                  Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: Hey Rakesh, did you run bundle install? What is the output? And when does this error occur exactly? could you maybe also add the gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Open console from windows (start menu and enter cmd) or linux (ctrl + alt + t) and write
gem install sqlite3 then press enter.